# AlarmManager and Notifications in Android 8.0(Oreo)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, alarmmanager, android-8.0-oreo

In my app i have a alarm that is repeting every thursday, i am using AlarmManger, everything is working fine in all previous versions of android, but now with android 8.0(oreo), the alarm Isn't firing, below is the classes that i use to set my alarm.
From what i searched i need to set the alarm explicitly, but I 
dont understand how.

MainActivity:

```
try
        {
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
            PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = GetSystemService(AlarmService).JavaCast<AlarmManager>();

            if (Settings.AccessAlarm == 0)
            {
                alarmManager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, BootReceiver.FirstReminder(), BootReceiver.reminderInterval, pending);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
                Settings.AccessAlarm = 1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Settings.AccessAlarm = 0;
        }
```

Bootreceiver.cs:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
public class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    //the interval currently every one minute
    //to set it to dayly change the value to 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    public static long reminderInterval = AlarmManager.IntervalDay * 7;
    //public static long reminderInterval = 3 * 1000;

    public static long FirstReminder()
    {
        System.Random rnd = new System.Random();

        int minutenumber = rnd.Next(20, 40);

        Java.Util.Calendar calendar = Java.Util.Calendar.Instance;
        calendar.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.DayOfWeek, Calendar.Thursday);
        calendar.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.HourOfDay, 10);
        calendar.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Minute, minutenumber);
        return calendar.TimeInMillis;

    }

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BootReceiver: OnReceive");
            var alarmIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
            var pending = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
            alarmManager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, FirstReminder(), reminderInterval, pending);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
            Settings.AccessAlarm = 1;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Settings.AccessAlarm = 0;
        }

    }
}
```

AlarmReceiver:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    private int z = 0;
    private int i;


    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        try
        {
                Settings.AlarmNotification = 1;

                if (System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
                {
                    Settings.AlarmCount =0;
                }

                var title = "Test";
                var message = "Something";

                Intent backIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
                backIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);



                var resultIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));



                PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.GetActivities(context, 0,
                    new Intent[] { backIntent, resultIntent },
                    PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

                var builder =
                    new Notification.Builder(context)
                        .SetContentTitle(title)
                        .SetContentText(message)
                        .SetAutoCancel(true)
                        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
                        .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.All);

                builder.SetContentIntent(pending);
                var notification = builder.Build();
                var manager = NotificationManager.FromContext(context);
                manager.Notify(1331, notification);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your alarms would be firing correctly as you are using explicit intents. But in Oreo/API26 `.SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.All` is obsolete and will cause a silent failure and your notifications will not be displayed.

So you need to setup a notification channel to properly display your notification with all the bells and whistles.

If you replace your notification builder & notify code:

```
var builder =
    new Notification.Builder(context)
        .SetContentTitle(title)
~~~~
manager.Notify(1331, notification);
```

With an API check for Oreo/API26(+) you can established an notification channel for your app:

```
using (var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(context))
{
    Notification notification;
    if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt < Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
    {
        notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                                    .SetContentTitle(title)
                                    .SetContentText(message)
                                    .SetAutoCancel(true)
                                    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
                                    .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.All)
                                    .SetContentIntent(pending)
                                    .Build();
    }
    else
    {
        // Setup a NotificationChannel, Go crazy and make it public, urgent with lights, vibrations & sound.
        var myUrgentChannel = context.PackageName;
        const string channelName = "SushiHangover Urgent";

        NotificationChannel channel;
        channel = notificationManager.GetNotificationChannel(myUrgentChannel);
        if (channel == null)
        {
            channel = new NotificationChannel(myUrgentChannel, channelName, NotificationImportance.High);
            channel.EnableVibration(true);
            channel.EnableLights(true);
            channel.SetSound(
                RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification),
                new AudioAttributes.Builder().SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Notification).Build()
            );
            channel.LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public;
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        channel?.Dispose();

        notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                                    .SetChannelId(myUrgentChannel)
                                    .SetContentTitle(title)
                                    .SetContentText(message)
                                    .SetAutoCancel(true)
                                    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
                                    .SetContentIntent(pending)
                                    .Build();
    }
    notificationManager.Notify(1331, notification);
    notification.Dispose();
}
```

Now in settings, your app has a channel assigned to it that the user can customize if they so choose:

[image]

Comment: Hello,thanks alot for the help, now is working, but the icon on the notification is not showing, is normal in android 8.0?
Another thing, is possible to know if the user clicked in the notification?

Comment: @Phill The icon (`SetSmallIcon`) should be showing, does on my Oreo. You are setting the `Intent` of the notification (`backIntent`) and starting a new instance of the `MainActivity` (via `NewTask`), not sure if that is what you want or not. Accept this answer since it worked and post another question concerning the user clicking the notification if needed.

Comment: I will do that, whats your icon size in the drawable folder, mine is 48x48.

Comment: @Phill I use all of the sizes `ldpi` to `xxxhdpi`, 48x48 would be `xhdpi`, so that should work ok and would be scaled up and down... I also use the large icons : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setLargeIcon(android.graphics.Bitmap)

Comment: I have almost the same code as you but starting with Android 8+, when the device is restarted and a BOOT_COMPLETED is sent to the app, the app crashes with the following (I removed some text to shorten things): `RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver: IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED cmp=....GcmService (has extras) }: app is in background uid ...`