# Replacement for the obsolete Notification.Builder.SetPriority()?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to set up a notification on Android and am getting a warning by Visual Studio that [Notification.Builder.SetPriority()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Notification+Builder.SetPriority/p/System.Int32/) is obsolete.

Is there a replacement for it? Android suggests [SetImportance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setPriority(int)) but that doesn't seem to be included in Xamarin.

Comment: is `setPriority` obsolete or deprecated, i doubt ?? you can try `notificationcompat.builder.setPriority`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This method was deprecated in API level 26.
>   use setImportance(int) instead.

`SetImportance` is contained in API26 within a `NotificationChannel` and can be set as a property on the channel, or within the `NotificationChannel` constructor:

```
channel.Importance = NotificationImportance.High
```

or

```
channel = new NotificationChannel(myUrgentChannel, channelName, NotificationImportance.High);
```

#### Conditional API Notification Example:

```
var title = "Note from Sushi";
var message = "StackOverflow is a really great source of information";
using (var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(BaseContext))
{
    Notification notification;
    if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt < Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
    {
        notification = new Notification.Builder(BaseContext)
                                             .SetContentTitle(title)
                                             .SetContentText(message)
                                             .SetAutoCancel(true)
                                             .SetPriority(1)
                                             .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
                                             .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.All)
                                             .Build();
    }
    else
    {
        var myUrgentChannel = PackageName;
        const string channelName = "SushiHangover Urgent";

        NotificationChannel channel;
        channel = notificationManager.GetNotificationChannel(myUrgentChannel);
        if (channel == null)
        {
            channel = new NotificationChannel(myUrgentChannel, channelName, NotificationImportance.High);
            channel.EnableVibration(true);
            channel.EnableLights(true);
            channel.LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public;
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        channel?.Dispose();

        notification = new Notification.Builder(BaseContext)
                                             .SetChannelId(myUrgentChannel)
                                             .SetContentTitle(title)
                                             .SetContentText(message)
                                             .SetAutoCancel(true)
                                             .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
                                             .Build();
    }
    notificationManager.Notify(1331, notification);
    notification.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that `Build.VERSION.SdkInt` refers to the version I'm _building_ with, but would run fine even on devices with lower than Oreo. Right?

Comment: @ispiro The `Build.VERSION` is the build of the actual OS running on the device, so in this case, if the device is less then Oreo, use the older style of notifications, otherwise use the new Ore0 channel based way. Make sense?

Comment: Thanks. So I guess we have to use an obsolete method. (Very few devices will be running O today. Around 1% according to [Android](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).)

Comment: @ispiro If you do not choose to include both the old and new methods and your code is running on those 1.1% of Oreo devices, might want to check you are not experiencing silent failures of your notifications ;-( https://stackoverflow.com/q/47750935/4984832

Comment: Thanks! I now appreciate Microsoft more. They mark methods as deprecated long before they are not supported anymore. If Xamarin could do the same for Android by supporting some obsolete methods by calling the appropriate platform methods that would be nice...

Comment: Does the channelID have to be the PackageName as you use in your example here and in thte answer you linked to?

Comment: @ispiro No, channelID can be anything you want, it does needs to be unique to your app : `The id of the channel. Must be unique per package. The value may be truncated if it is too long.` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html#NotificationChannel(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int)