# How to play custom sound in Xamarin.Forms on Android using Local Notifications / Notification.Builder

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, notifications, xamarin.android

I am trying to play a custom sound on the Android platform when a local notification is being displayed, the code below is based on the Xamarin [Local Notification Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications), but some fields I'm being nagged are obsolete/deprecated.

In particular, **SetSound**

I have however tried using SetSound in the hope that it could still work, even if deprecated.  But I am not sure how to reference either the mp3 files in the Android / Xamarin 'Asset' folder or the copy that I have in Android / Xamarin 'Resources/raw' folder.

/Asset contents has build action AndroidAsset

/Resources/raw contents has build action AndroidResource

This line is what is causing me the headaches ...

.SetSound(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://MyAssemblyName.Droid/Assets/filename"));

also tried

.SetSound(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://MyAssemblyName.Resources/raw/filename"));

Q1) What do I need to do to correctly play a custom notification sound using either the Assets or Resources folder?

Q2) Because SetSound deprecated, what am I meant to do instead?

I have cheated, partially successfully, I have a Xamarin Plugin that plays sounds, which references the same files in the portable class library (PCL) and that mechanism works (when un-commented), but only if the app is in the foreground.

It seems that my scheduled local notifications do not trigger if I swipe to 'kill' the app, even though the app will not die because I have a persistent notification that prevents the app closing (until a certain time in the future that releases the persistent notification which could be minutes later).

Q3) Why don't the scheduled local notifications trigger once the user swipes the app, even though a persistent system notification keeps the app running?  Here's how that persistent notification is set up. If it wasn't for this issue I could probably get by with the hack detailed above to play the sound from the PCL.

```
        var activity = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity));
        var pIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, activity, 0);

        var notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .SetContentTitle("Persistent Notification Test")
            .SetContentText("This is always running to ensure that you are safe.")
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
            .SetOngoing(true)
            .SetDefaults(0) // no sounds
            .SetContentIntent(pIntent)
            .Build();

        // Enlist this instance of the service as a foreground service
        StartForeground(SERVICE_RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

For those interested, the commented out line

```
// PlatformDifferences.PlaySound(soundFilename, Logger);
```

calls through to this method that uses the SimpleAudioPlayer plugin

```
    public virtual void PlaySound(string soundFilenameExcludingPath, Logger logger) {
        var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(App)).Assembly;

        Stream audioStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("<my-pcl-assembly-name>.Sounds." + soundFilenameExcludingPath);
            if (audioStream != null)
            {
                logger.Log(this, "playing sound:" + soundFilenameExcludingPath);
                var player = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
                player.Load(audioStream);
                player.Play();
            }
            else
            {
                logger.Log(this, "failed - playing sound:" + soundFilenameExcludingPath);
            }
    }
```

Here's a screenshot that shows my project structure

[image: Screenshot of resource and asset folder with code snippet]

And here's the method that I invoke whenever I want to display a notification, whether because I wanted a scheduled local notification, or because I've received a push notification and wish to show the details to the user.

```
    private async Task DisplayLocalNotification(String title, String message, String soundFilename)
    {

        Logger.Log(this, "DisplayLocalNotification title:" + title + " message:" + message);

        // Ensure the main activity is lauched when the app is started.
        Intent secondIntent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity));

        Notification.BigTextStyle textStyle = new Notification.BigTextStyle();
        textStyle.BigText(message);
        int length = message.Length;
        if (length > 80)
        {
            length = 80;
        }
        textStyle.SetSummaryText(message.Substring(0, length));

        const int pendingIntentId = 0;
        PendingIntent pendingEventForMainActivity =
            PendingIntent.GetActivity(Android.App.Application.Context, pendingIntentId, secondIntent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(Android.App.Application.Context)
            .SetContentTitle(title)
            .SetContentText(message)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingEventForMainActivity)
            //.SetWhen () // - Now
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
            .SetVisibility(NotificationVisibility.Public) 
            .SetCategory(Notification.CategoryEvent)
            .SetStyle(textStyle)
            //.SetSound(Asset);?? What import?
            //.SetSound(RingtoneManager.) ?? Looks like it's a fixed list of alert sounds
            .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound | NotificationDefaults.Vibrate) // << DEPRECATD
            .SetSound(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://My-Assembly.Droid/Assets/" + soundFilename)); // << DEPECATD

        // Hack - Works (if in foreground, but no if swipe-to-kill)...
        // PlatformDifferences.PlaySound(soundFilename, Logger);

        // Example: .SetSound(Uri.Parse("android.resource://" + this.PackageName + "/Raw/" + Resource.Raw.woop));

        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
        {
            builder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon);// Resource.Drawable.icon_transparent);
        }
        else
        {
            builder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon);
        }

        // Create a task stack builder to manage the back stack:
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(Android.App.Application.Context);

        // Add all parents of SecondActivity to the stack: 
        stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(MainActivity)));

        // Push the intent that starts SecondActivity onto the stack:
        stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(secondIntent);

        // Build the notification:
        Notification androidNotification = builder.Build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
            Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

        // Publish the notification:
        int notificationId = await StorageService.increment(Constants.STORAGE_KEY_NOTIFICATION_COUNTER);
        notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, androidNotification);

        Console.Out.WriteLine("DisplayLocalNotification title:" + title + " message:" + message + " published as id:" + notificationId + "?");

    }
```

Comment: I see that your using an API-27 device, but assuming you are not targeting a version (i.e. `android:targetSdkVersion=`) and thus not using the new `NotificationChannel` and how to `.SetSound` on them, refer to my answer here as a start:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47753060/4984832

Comment: You can read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification). Please use  `NotificationCompat`.

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover, I am currently targeting API 23+ but will be changing this minimum 23 target 26+.  May I ask why you think I'm using an API-27 device? I'm not sure that I undertand.

Comment: Thanks @JoeLv-MSFT thats a great resource and will prove very useful - however it doesn't mention setting a custom sound and that's kinda critical for what I am working on.

Comment: @DevologyLtd Not talking about the `minSdkVersion`, talking about `targetSdkVersion` (Xamarin does not set it if you are using "Automatic" for that setting). Your screen shot is showing a API-27 device and if `targetSdkVersion` was set, you would be required to use `NotificationChannel`s (you would need to if/else test the API levels as in my linked example). I have seen a lot of different type of notification failures on different (API-26+) devices, even notifications in the  emulators behave different when not using NotificationChannels.

Comment: Ah thanks @SushiHangover that makes a lot of sense - I'll update you once I've given that a go.

Comment: @SushiHangover seems to be working a treat now, however, I did notice some people saying I needed to drop the .mp3 extension when passing the SetSound method into the Uri, but I'm now referencing the Resource instead (int instead of String), so I suspect it might have worked if I had originally done that, but I am happy with the additional options available (different categories of notifications that the user can now configure in their phone settings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the comments from @SushiHangover

> Your screen shot is showing a API-27 device and if targetSdkVersion
>   was set, you would be required to use NotificationChannels (you would
>   need to if/else test the API levels as in my linked example). I have
>   seen a lot of different type of notification failures on different
>   (API-26+) devices, even notifications in the emulators behave
>   different when not using NotificationChannels.